Nextjs shadcn Cannot update a component (`LoginForm`) while rendering a different component (`Controller`)
This Nextjs component give me this error, why? I can't find the bug and it's pretty annoying because it does't let user to login in and it doesn't show any error message.
I'm using shadcn UI library, and it seems that the problem come from 'Controller':
app-index.js:35 Warning: Cannot update a component (LoginForm) while rendering a different component (Controller). To locate the bad setState() call inside Controller
"use client"
import { ExclamationTriangleIcon, EyeOpenIcon } from "@radix-ui/react-icons"
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import { z } from "zod"
import { Button } from "./ui/button"
import { Input } from "./ui/input"
import { Form, FormField, FormItem, FormControl, FormMessage, } from "./ui/form"
import loginFormSchema from "@/lib/zod-schemas/LoginFormSchema"
import { useState, useTransition } from "react"
import { login } from "@/actions/auth/login"
import { Alert, AlertTitle, AlertDescription } from "./ui/alert"

export default function LoginForm() {
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition()
  const [error, setError] = useState<undefined | string>("");
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof loginFormSchema>>({
      resolver: zodResolver(loginFormSchema),
      defaultValues: {
          username: '',
          password: '',
      }
  })

  async function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof loginFormSchema>) {
    setError("");
    startTransition(async () => {
      const data = await login(values);
      setError(data?.error?.toString());
    })
  }

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
    <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-2">
      <FormField
      control={form.control}
      name="username"
      disabled={isPending}
      render={({ field }) => (
        <FormItem>
        <FormControl>
          <Input placeholder="Username" {...field} />
        </FormControl>
        <FormMessage />
        </FormItem>
      )}
      />
      <FormField
      control={form.control}
      name="password"
      disabled={isPending}
      render={({ field }) => (
        <FormItem>
        <FormControl>
          <Input
            type="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
            placeholder="Password"
            {...field}
          />
          {/* <div className="flex items-center py-4">
            <EyeOpenIcon className="relative left-7 top-2 transform -translate-y-1/2"/>
            <Input
              type="password"
              autoComplete="current-password"
              placeholder="Password"
              className="max-w-sm pl-10"
              {...field}
            />
          </div> */}
        </FormControl>
        <FormMessage />
        </FormItem>
      )}
      />
      {
      error && (
        <Alert variant="destructive">
        <ExclamationTriangleIcon className="h-4 w-4" />
        <AlertTitle>Error</AlertTitle>
        <AlertDescription>
          {error}
        </AlertDescription>
        </Alert>
      )
      }
      <Button disabled={isPending} type="submit" className="w-full">Log in</Button>
    </form>
    </Form>
  )
}

This is my login function
"use server"

import { z } from "zod";
import { AuthError } from "next-auth";
import loginFormSchema from "@/lib/zod-schemas/LoginFormSchema";
import { signIn } from "@/auth";
import { DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT } from "@/routes";

export async function login(values: z.infer<typeof loginFormSchema>) {
    const validateField = loginFormSchema.safeParse(values);
    if (!validateField.success) {
        return { error: validateField.error }
    }
    const { username, password } = validateField.data;
    try {
        await signIn('credentials', {
            username,
            password,
            redirectTo: DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT
        })
    } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof AuthError) {
            switch (e.type) {
                case "CredentialsSignin":
                    return { error: 'Invalid credentials!'}
                default:
                    return { error: 'Something went wrong!'}
            }
        }
        throw e;
    }
}


Related discussion: https://github.com/orgs/react-hook-form/discussions/10964

I was having the same problem, I tried removing the disabled={isPending} from inside the FormField and passing it to the Input, and it started working again.
 <FormField
  control={form.control}
  name="password"
  render={({ field }) => (
    <FormItem>
    <FormControl>
      <Input
        type="password"
        disabled={isPending}
        autoComplete="current-password"
        placeholder="Password"
        {...field}
      />

